# Heroku: ImportError: No module named site

Tags: python, heroku, importerror

After some changes in my repo and deploy to heroku I am receiving the following error:

ImportError: No module named site

I not have idea what can cause the problem because I only change some Django templates in the last 2 commits.

Best Regards

Comment: Nobody will be able to help you without more information. If everything really is in source control then you could give us a diff between the last time you had it working and now.

Comment: I am getting the same error while upgrading from django 1.5 to 1.6. I think it has to do with the admin site being enabled by default. I don't know how to fix it yet though.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at your Procfile. It should show something like this:

```
web: gunicorn site:app
```

Make sure `site` is the name of your app.

Answer (score 4):

Heroku has an article for this: https://help.heroku.com/BWJ7QYTF/why-am-i-seeing-importerror-no-module-named-site-when-deploying-a-python-app

Updates to the Python buildpack mean that the PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME config vars being set on the app may introduce this issue.

> Firstly, check if these are present with
>
> `heroku config`
>
> To fix the issue, you can unset them like so:
>
> `heroku config:unset PYTHONHOME -a appname`
>
> `heroku config:unset PYTHONPATH -a appname`

Answer (score -1):

Add the following to your proc file

```
web: gunicorn site:app
```

Also check your gitignore and make sure site isnt included

Comment: how is this different from previous answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/34800194/7237062 (gitignore part set aside) ?!