# Confusing error while deploying Django on Heroku: No module named site

Tags: django, heroku

I've got two Heroku apps, running on the same codebase. The 1st is used as staging env and it works as expected (it auto deploys the devel branch) and the 2nd is used as the production app (auto deploying the master branch).
Today I did a minor code-level change and submitted a PR from devel to master and merged it. From that moment, heroku cannot deploy my master branch in production.

Full logs for this as given by heroku build log:
----->

```
 Python app detected
-----> Uninstalling stale dependencies
       Uninstalling django-elasticsearch-0.5:
         Successfully uninstalled django-elasticsearch-0.5
       Uninstalling pymongo-3.3.0:
         Successfully uninstalled pymongo-3.3.0
     $ pip install -r requirements.txt
       Collecting git+https://github.com/liberation/django_elasticsearch.git (from -r requirements.txt (line 69))
         Cloning https://github.com/liberation/django_elasticsearch.git to /tmp/pip-ZPaLWp-build
       Collecting Delorean==0.6.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 10))
         Downloading Delorean-0.6.0.tar.gz
       Collecting humanize==0.5.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 37))
         Downloading humanize-0.5.1.tar.gz
       Collecting pynamodb==2.0.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 46))
         Downloading pynamodb-2.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (73kB)
       Collecting tzlocal==1.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 63))
         Downloading tzlocal-1.3.tar.gz
       Installing collected packages: humanize, tzlocal, Delorean, django-traffic, pynamodb, django-elasticsearch
         Running setup.py install for humanize: started
           Running setup.py install for humanize: finished with status 'done'
         Running setup.py install for tzlocal: started
           Running setup.py install for tzlocal: finished with status 'done'
         Running setup.py install for Delorean: started
           Running setup.py install for Delorean: finished with status 'done'
         Running setup.py install for django-elasticsearch: started
           Running setup.py install for django-elasticsearch: finished with status 'done'
       Successfully installed Delorean-0.6.0 django-elasticsearch-0.5 django-traffic-1.2.4 humanize-0.5.1 pynamodb-2.0.2 tzlocal-1.3
-----> Django app detected
-----> Running Django migrations
ImportError: No module named site
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Django app.
 !     Push failed
```

Well, as fas as I know, there's no "site" module/app or anything in my code, so I cannot understand what's the problem in this case. I remind you, the devel branch auto deploys as expected in the respective Heroku app.

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of Django/Python are you using? Also, check to see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12703388/heroku-importerror-no-module-named-site

Comment: @Hybrid unfortunately I've seen that before and it didn't help :/ I use python 2.7. My local virtualenv and the python runtime in both apps (production and staging) is python2.7