# Issue with Python OpenCV custom buildpack on Heroku

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, heroku, bottle

I am trying to host my Bottle app on Heroku.The app uses OpenCV.

I have tried using the custom buildpacks available , but I get the following error and the app crashes.

```
2017-04-19T16:46:56.977606+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-04-19T16:46:56.861136+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named site
2017-04-19T16:46:56.992302+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Tried the solution in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12703388/heroku-importerror-no-module-named-site) and the pointer there,but not able to fix it

The build log doesnt look convincing :

```
Python + OpenCV + Numpy + Scipy app detected
cp: ‘/tmp/build_23d686801ba84fdb080f034e9c7976a5/.heroku/python’ and ‘/app/.heroku/python’ are the same file
-----> Generating environment
       Fetching...
       Unpacking...
bzip2: (stdin) is not a bzip2 file.
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
-----> Found requirements.txt, installing dependencies using pip
/app/tmp/buildpacks/6d14a3412dcdb0901c57e73e48ec9af7391889a6a8ae9eafff2088dea5ddcd7dc5f2da12110056dc6e443347c536c173b8187008e003291c29f8a6d30faa87a1/bin/compile: line 84: /app/.heroku/vendor/bin/pip: No such file or directory
-----> Creating environment variables.
-----> Buildpack installed.
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 41.7M
-----> Launching...
       Released v6
       https://tncs.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I think the problem is that opencv is a library that needs to be downloaded, unzipped and compiled by heroku before it can be used. Are you using a heroku build pack for opencv? If so, you might consider switching to another build pack that indirectly uses opencv.

I switched over to the anaconda build pack and my opencv flask app works now. Take a look!

https://github.com/kennethreitz/conda-buildpack

This build pack allows you to specify a conda-requirements.txt file, which you can use to include opencv.

The steps I followed to deploy an opencv Heroku app were:

create a web app and link it to a heroku project

1. heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/kennethreitz/conda-buildpack
2. add a file called "conda-requirements.txt" to the same directory as your web app and add "opencv" to the file.
3. deploy the app and check to make sure that heroku is giving you 
   something like this in the output:

remote: # packages in environment at /app/.heroku/miniconda:

remote: #

remote: opencv 3.1.0 np112py27_1

if it doesn't work, check the heroku logs to make sure the problem is with the build pack. If you're only trying to get opencv to work, only use this anaconda build pack, don't add any other build packs. Hope that helps!